# Access MQTT asynchronous messages

Tags: java, mqtt, iot

I have a listener class(Java) that is subscribed to several topics via MQTT. I want to access the messages that are published to my listener from another class. How to do this?
The goal is to feed the output of the listener class into a continuously refreshing JFrame.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a client

```
private MqttClient sampleClient;
```

you need to subscribe to some topics:

```
sampleClient.subscribe(topicToSubscribe);
```

and SET A CALLBACK so you can get the info that the broker is pushing to you (this is for sure what you are missing)

```
   sampleClient.setCallback(new MqttCallback() {

   @Override
    public void messageArrived(String topicInforming, MqttMessage mqttMessage) throws Exception {
                 System.out.println("messageArrived: " + mqttMessage.toString());
            }

   @Override
   public void deliveryComplete(IMqttDeliveryToken arg0) {
                System.out.println("DeliveryComplete: " + arg0.getMessageId());
            }

   @Override
    public void connectionLost(Throwable arg0) {
                System.err.println("Connection lost: " + arg0.getMessage());
    }
});
```